# How to import data from a database and store it in a variable in a node.js app for later use

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, socket.io

I want to try and get data from a database(in my case, questions) and save them in an array to be used in the rest of my javascript code.

I have been doing some reading and tests with mysql in node.js, and how it is asynchronous. I've been able to get the data after querying, but I can't store the data elsewhere in my code, and I want to know what to do to get the database data, store it, and use it for other areas in my js code.

Here is one of my tests

This is part of the **server** javascript

```
var questions;

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('Get Questions', function(){

        const db = mysql.createConnection({
            host: "localhost",
            database: "playerdb",
            user: "root",
            password: "061298"
        });

        db.query("SELECT Question FROM quiz_questions", function(err, results){
            //if(err) console.log("Oh dear, " + err);
    
            for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
                questions.push(results[i]);
            }
        })
    });

    io.sockets.emit('Send Questions', questions);
});
```

Here is part of the **client** javascript

```
    socket.emit('Get Questions');

    socket.on('Send Questions', function(qList){
        for(var c = 0; c < questions.length; c++){
            const newQuestion = document.createElement('li');
            newQuestion.innerHTML = qList[i];
    
            databaseData.appendChild(newQuestion);
        }
    })
```

This code returns the error:
"Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize your array before you can `push` to it

```
let questions = [];
```

Comment: That seemed to fix the storing aspect. 
I managed to make some alterations afterwards and everything is now working as intended. Thanks!